# Como puedo mandarle un parámetro de limite en vez de ponerle +10

Tags: javascript, jquery

> Aca genero el calendario en el campo fechafin, pero lo que necesito es que en vez de +10(dias que es lo que habilita en el calendario y el resto de dias estan bloqueados para seleccionar)

```
$(function(){
        $('#fechafin').datebox().datebox('calendar').calendar({
            validator: function(date){
                var now = new Date();
                var d1 = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
                var d2 = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()+10);
                return d1<=date && date<=d2;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Desde donde quieres enviarle un parámetro?

Comment: <label>Documento</label>
    <input id="documento" name="documento" class="easyui-datebox">                                                                                          //Que esta no se pase de la fecha que toma aca @crrlos